# Prove the complex Inequality $|z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1| + |z_2|$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I have to be prove the following inequality, where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two complex numbers.
$$|z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1| + |z_2|$$

I know I can substitute Z as 'x + iy' and open both sides but I am confused about the inequality. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This inequality is equivalent to the geometric triangle inequality, because $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ where $x = \mathrm{Re}\, z, y = \mathrm{Im}\,z$.

Comment: you can square the whole inequality